# Trying to give margin to evenly divs inside a container

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contained one">foobar</div>
    <div class="contained two">foobar</div>
</div>    

-- css --

.container {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
.contained {   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.one {
    background: blue;
}
.two{
    background: green;
}
```

I would like to give a margin around to the contained `divs`, but I don't know how..

Comment: It's just like Padding.  margin: 10px;

Comment: If you are using a fixed width for the container, why use % on the width?  I find using pixels easier than % when dealing with padding/margin.

Comment: @JonHarding mmm.. Your comment seems interesting.. I'm bit newbie with css.. I'm was giving a `width: 50%` to get two divs with the same dimensions and occupying alwasy the same proportion in the container div..

Comment: @tirengario. True, but if you have a fixed with there is never going to be a variable width for the interior boxes. I either always use percentages together or pixels, I rarely combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like Padding.  `margin: 10px;` for example.

Note that margin needs to be calculated into the width of your elements also.  So I suggest giving % margins, then make sure your total % of margins plus your widths = 100%.

You could do something like...

```
.contained {   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This works because (2.5left + 2.5right) * 2 boxes = 10% total margin space... Then 10% + 45% per box is 10% + 90% = 100%

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krvyJ/15/)

---

**Response to your question in comments:**

Because your container has a certain width, no matter what that width may be, only so much can fit inside it.  The way CSS is coded, the "TOTAL" width of any element includes its defined width, any border space, padding and margin.  This is the default way that any element operates.  In the code above, you have box-sizing: border-box.  This tells the browser to calculate the "width" property including padding and border.  Unfortunately there isn't a code that also includes margin space.

So imagine it like this.  You have a box that can fit 100 100 balls in it, and still close the lid of the box.  If you have 101 balls, the lid will not close.  So lets say you want to fit 50 blue balls and 50 red balls in the box.  You can still close the lid because you don't exceed the 100 ball limit.  Now let's say you want a certain amount of space between the 50 red balls and 50 blue balls.  Let's imagine this space is just empty "air", but in reality, air actually takes up space too.  So in order to fit 10 "ball units" worth of air "space" between the two groups of balls, one of two things needs to happen in order to still close the lid of the box.

You can either make the box 10 units larger for a total 110 "ball units" - 50 for the red balls, 50 for the blue balls, and 10 for the air separating the two groups.  OR, you can remove a few of the balls that are already inside the container in order to fit the 10 "ball units" of air.  So you could have 45 blue balls, and 45 red balls and 10 units of air to = 100 and close the lid on the box.  As long as the number of red balls, blue balls, and air equals your boxes maximum 100 ball units, then they can fit and u can close the lid.  Any combination could be used.  For example you could have, 10 red balls, 10 blue balls, 10 green balls, 10 yellow balls, and 10 purple balls with 10 units of air after each group.  That is...

10red + 10air + 10blue + 10air + 10green + 10air + 10yellow + 10 air + 10purple + 10 air

10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10 = 100

Now... That said, if you hadn't used `box-sizing: border-box;` then you would also have to include padding and border in your calculations along with margin.

Comment: thanks, but if I give a margin, the second div goes down..I want to maintain both divs in the same vertical position. Here you have: http://jsfiddle.net/krvyJ/14/

Comment: @MartinBerocochea your example also moves down the socond div. I want to maintain them in the same vertical position.

Comment: thanks, I'm still newbie with CSS, so I'm a bit surprised with your answer.. My question: why is not just enough writing the margins? In the way you propose, I have to change the width when I change the margins. There not any way to give full width to the contained divs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H26kZ/).

Only changed the one CSS block

```
.contained {   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 46.25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:2.5% 0 2.5% 2.5%;
}
```

This creates even spacing all the way around the blocks.